# Plotly histogram not showing properly

Tags: python, plot, histogram, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a dataset shaped like this:

```
   country  VS          FS          NVS         NS          DK
0   Ger     0.232166    0.619047    0.118365    0.025656    0.004765
1   Greece  0.075576    0.434646    0.312487    0.176326    0.000965
2   Italy   0.093241    0.604096    0.236266    0.062316    0.004082
3   UK      0.362274    0.533966    0.080102    0.020687    0.002971
```

and I want to make an overlaid histogram using plotly, with countries on x-axis and the values of the columns on the y axis. My code is the following:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

trace1 = Histogram(
   x=data_mil.country,
   y=data_mil.NS,
   opacity=0.75
)
data = [trace1]
layout = Layout(barmode='overlay')
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

iplot(fig, filename='overlaid histogram')
```

and I add other traces for each column I want to be shown. By the way I get 
this histogram

[image]

where all the NS values are 1, and I can't figure out why. I have made several other plots in the same notebook (not histograms) and plotly is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plotly's `Bar` graph instead.

A histogram will give the distribution of values (per category: in your example per country).  However if there is only a single value 1.0 will be outputted. Consider the following example each category has a single value.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


data = [go.Histogram(
            x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y=[20, 14, 23]
    )]

py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

Results in this plot that resembles yours.
[image]

When we change `Histogram` for `Bar` like so.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


data = [go.Bar(
            x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y=[20, 14, 23]
    )]

py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

We get this plot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it worked. I definitely should have thought it by myself, that was an easy one.